# Load multiple files into multiple table using Dataflow pipeline(Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I wanted to create a dataflow job using python which reads multiple files from the gcs and load it into different tables, if I have 5 files, each of the file loads into each unique table. I could created Job for one file, but wanted to do that in a loop

Tried to create in a loop, but it failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mbal I proposed you an answer, can you check it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list of configuration containing files or pathes associated to the output dataset and table. Then loop on this list, and apply the pipeline for each element, example :

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    configured_inputs_outputs = [
        ("gs://bucket/folder/file1.txt", "dataset", "table1"),
        ("gs://bucket2/folder/file*.txt", "dataset", "table2")
    ]

    for bucket_path, dataset, table in configured_inputs_outputs:
        (p
         | f"Read File from text file for table {table}" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(bucket_path)
         | f"write to table {table}" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    project="project",
                    dataset=dataset,
                    table=table,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
         )
```

In this example, the configuration contains :

- The file path or path with a wildcard if you want to load multiple files if needed for a table
- The output `BigQuery` dataset
- The output `BigQuery` table

We loop on this list :

- Use `ReadFromText` input connector from the configured input file path
- You can add transformations after if needed
- Use `WriteToBigQuery` output connector from the configured output dataset and table